# Handling IAP Fullfilment results for Windows 10 Store

Tags: in-app-purchase, windows-10-universal, windows-dev-center

When providing consumable In App Purchases on the Windows 10 Store, there are FullfillmentResults when ReportConsumableFullfillmentAsync is called.

The user of my app has had their IAP fullfilled by the time I get this result. This means they have their Coins/Gems/Potatoes.

But if I receive **FulfillmentResult.PurchaseReverted**, then what happened? How did the user just revert the purchase? Am I meant to withdraw their Coins/Gems/Potatoes?

What are scenarios behind the other error messages?

Note: I'm working with using **Windows.ApplicationModel.Store**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if I receive FulfillmentResult.PurchaseReverted, then what
>   happened? How did the user just revert the purchase? Am I meant to
>   withdraw their Coins/Gems/Potatoes?

The value `PurchaseReverted` means the transaction is canceled on the backend and users get their money back. So you should disable the user's access to the cosumable content (withdraw the `Coins/Gems/Potatoes`) as necessary.

> What are scenarios behind the other error messages?

`NothingToFulfill` : The transaction id has been fulfilled or is otherwise complete

`PurchasePending`: The purchase is not complete. At this point it is still possible for the transaction to be reversed due to provider failures and/or risk checks. It means the purchase has not yet cleared and could still be revoked.

`ServerError`: There was an issue receiving fulfillment status. It might be the problem from the Store.

`Succeed`: The fulfillment is complete and your `Coins/Gems/Potatoes` can be offered again.

Here is the documentation about [**FulfillmentResult Enum**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.fulfillmentresult)

Comment: Would it be good practice to withhold the IAP until the purchase is has a status of NothingtoFullfill, instead of reverting the sale upon failure?

If they get their Coins/Gems/Potatoes then they could quickly spend them before the refund occurs. Either on purpose, or not.